# How to hide nginx version via update traefik ingress yaml with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, nginx-ingress, traefik-ingress

I have an application on a Kubernetes cluster that is deployed through Helm.
The ingress controller is installed by the command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.47.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

How to hide the nginx version from header responce?

At this moment I have next ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-tokens: "off"
```

So maybe i need change to
`traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/response-headers`: and some rules...

I'm checking response with `curl -IL mysite.com`
In response i got next: **Server: nginx/1.21.3**

Give me and advice please)

i'm added `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-tokens: "off"` but it not help me.
Expect to hide nginx version with `helm update` or `kubectl install` new ingress yaml

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation for the nginx controller, it says:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/

| Annotation | onfigMap Key | Description | Description | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nginx.org/server-tokens | server-tokens | Enables or disables the server_tokens directive. Additionally, with the NGINX Plus, you can specify a custom string value, including the empty string value, which disables the emission of the “Server” field. | Default |  |

I suspect the following annotation should work:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.org/server-tokens: false
```

Note you could also customise it with a ConfigMap according to the docs.

And related to your comment on:

> traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/response-headers

Traefik is another ingress controller different from the nginx one, the configuration won't be the same.